# Encrypt String in java and decrypt it in winrt c#

Tags: c#, encryption, base64, encryption-symmetric, encryption-asymmetric

How one would encrypt a string using symmetric/asymmetric decryption on WinRT Metro in C# and encrypt this in java, let's say in a webservice?

I want to use RsaPkcs7 algorithm and I can see that CryptographicKey class and RSAParameters class are not even near compatible.

How this could be accomplished?

Answer (score 0):

There is [an example in MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.x509certificates.x509certificate2.aspx#exampleToggle) and [I made a Java port](http://artplastika.ru/vestnik/x509-java/) of it.